# java.util.HashMap.KeySet is not public in java.util.HashMap; cannot be accessed from outside package

Tags: java, hashmap, is-empty, keyset

Working with maps in a REPL to test out functionality and got this message when trying to run the .isEmpty() function on a map.

Here's what was entered in the console after creating a map:

```
acronyms.isEmpty();
```

Any idea what might cause this? I am just trying to troubleshoot my map in a REPL so not an actual program but I'm curious about this error message as I thought that .isEmpty() was built into the functionality of maps.

Thanks!

Comment: Please show us exactly what you did.

Comment: I took the map I created and ran the .isEmpty() function on it in the console, generating the above error.

Comment: So it looked like: acronyms.isEmpty(); and generated the error you see on the title.

Comment: Done. New to stack sorry.

Comment: Can you also explain what REPL?

Answer (score 0):

You get the entrySet() from a map, not Map.KeySet.